Flash memory code migration from STM32F4 to STM32L4+ series
I have a function that was implemented for STM32F4 discovery board and needs to be migrated to STM32L4R9I.
static void hal_flash_bank_stm32_write(void * context, int bank, uint32_t offset, const uint8_t * data, uint32_t size)
{
    hal_flash_bank_stm32_t * self = (hal_flash_bank_stm32_t *) context;

    if (bank > 1) return;
    if (offset > self->sector_size) return;
    if ((offset + size) > self->sector_size) return;

    unsigned int i;
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE, self->banks[bank] + offset + i, data[i]);
    }
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
}

The STM32L4R9I does not provide FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE but rather FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD. I am struggling with how to write all bytes properly. I tried the following:
uint64_t dword = 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    dword = (dword << 8) | data[i];
    if (i > 0 && i % 8 == 0)
    {
        uint32_t addr = self->banks[bank] + offset + i;
        HAL_FLASH_PROGRAM(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, addr, dword);
        dword = 0;
    }
}

I am currently unable to test my logic on a board. Is my logic correct or am I missing something?

Aren't the F and L families using entirely different flash? I vaguely recall this being the case.

It looks like you'll program the data from source offset 0 into flash at offset 8, which is wrong. If your length isn't a multiple of 8, you'll not program the last few bytes, since you'll never "fill up" your dword.
Here's a function paraphrased from a project I did on an STM32G0 (which also uses double-word flash writes):
static int do_copy( uint32_t * copy_from, uint32_t len, uint32_t copy_to )
{
    int status = 0;

    for ( uint32_t i = 0u; i < len; i += sizeof (uint64_t) )
    {
        HAL_StatusTypeDef hal_result;
        uint64_t          datum = 0u;

#if SOURCE_IS_DWORD_ALIGNED
        datum = * ( uint64_t * ) (copy_from + i);
#else
        for (uint32_t j = 0u; j < sizeof (uint64_t); j++)
        {
            datum = (datum << 8) | copy_from[i + j];
        }
#endif
        
        hal_result = HAL_FLASH_Program ( FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, copy_to + i,
                                         datum );
        if ( hal_result != HAL_OK )
        {
            status = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return status;
}

If you can guarantee that your data source is dword aligned, you can read an entire uint64_t in one go, and do away with the inner loop, as shown in one branch of the code above.
